# How i get this powershell dynamic script working?

Tags: powershell

Hello everyone i need this script to work and i'm stuck with a error.
I need to have a dynamic script with user choice and linking the mailbox we enter in first step to the HR choice.

In the csv part we have a group distribution list

Error says that i can not do the add-distributiongroupmember and i don't know why
can someone help me on this one ?

(I just do the 0 part choice because i need this one to work before doing the other choice)
code below

---

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline

$User = Read-Host "Enter Name of the mailbox to add"

Try {

$Mbx = Get-Mailbox -Identity $User -ErrorAction Stop | Select -ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress}

Catch {

Write-Host "No mailbox can be found called" $User; break }

$Services = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new('&Services')

$Services.HelpMessage = 'Get running services'

$HR = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&HR', 'Get running HRDL'

$Legal = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Legal', 'Get running LegalDL'

$Quit = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Quit', 'Quit menu'

$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($HR, $Legal, $Quit)

$Result = $host.UI.PromptForChoice('Task menu', 'Select a Department', $options , 0 )

$DLs = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\GregorySemedo\Desktop\Script\DL\DL-HR.csv"

switch($Result)



{



0 { ForEach ($DL in $DLs) {

Try {

Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DL."HR" -Member $Mbx -ErrorAction Continue }

Catch {

Write-Host "Couldn't add" $Mbx "to DL" (Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $DL."HR").DisplayName }

If($?)

{

Write-Host $User Succesfully added -ForegroundColor Green

}

Else

{

Write-Host $User - Error occurred -ForegroundColor Red

}}

}

}
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you're getting? (cut and paste the text from the console / log text *into your question* rather than posting a screenshot or adding it as a comment).

Comment: + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (XXXXXXX:String) [Add-DistributionGroupM

ember], RecipientTaskException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=XXX,RequestId=XXXX,TimeStamp

=14/06/2022 09:04:05] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-RecipientTaskException] C717D093,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.AddDistributionGroupMember

+ PSComputerName : outlook.office365.co

Comment: I think you've truncated your error message - there should be a message and a line number in your script. Can you look again and post the full message and edit it *into your question* (not as a comment). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.2#throw for the example of ```PS> Start-Something``` for what a full error message looks like...

Comment: @mclayton you have the full message on the first message

Comment: If that's all you're seeing then maybe temporarily disabling your ```try ... catch ...``` and see if you get any more useful info. ```+ CategoryInfo``` normally appears half way down the full error trace - the couple of lines before it give a message and the line of code that threw the exception - try running this in a interactive console and you'll see what I mean... ```function Start-Something { throw "Bad thing happened" }; Start-Something```.

Comment: So i managed to find the issue sorry for the trouble to everyone but it seems that this script work for distrib list but not for ms365 group i'm just a noob :)